# Getting the current item from a list in Python

Tags: python

The library I am using is executing a loop like this in Python.

```
for instance_set, label in self.file_loader(filenames):
   #some code
```

To debug I want to be able to print the current filename withing #somecode, since the is a crash within the  loop. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for filename, (instance_set, label) in zip(filenames, self.file_loader(filenames)):
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an outer loop

```
for fname in filenames:
    for instance_set, label in self.file_loader([fname]):
       print fname
```

Comment: Yes but that won't give me the filename on which the loop crashes.

Comment: You didn't ask about a crash, You asked how to print the filename in the loop which I demonstrated. If you need help debugging a crash, edit the post to reflect that and share the stack track.

Comment: Apologies, you are right, I have edited the question.